# How to cycle clients

Tags: window-manager, awesome

I want to be able to cycle clients within a single tag (screen).  I know I can swap clients by using `awful.client.swap.byidx` but that moves focus rather than the client.

Say I have three windows:

```
+---------+-----+
|         |     |
|         |  2  |
|         |     |
|   1     +-----|
|         |     |
|         |  3  |
|         |     |
+ --------+-----+
```

And I want to cycle each one into the "1" spot. So "1" would go to "2", "2" would go to "3", and "3" would go to "1".  Does that make sense

I know I've seen something like this, but can't find it now.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for (unsurprisingly) [`awesome.client.cycle`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html#cycle).  Add this to your rc.lua:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "y", function () awful.client.cycle(true)    end)
```

Then you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to get the desired behavior.  The lone boolean parameter determines cycle direction.

Comment: Actually for me that ended up working like the standard binding "awful.key({ modkey, "Shift"   }, "j", function () awful.client.swap.byidx(  1)    end)".

The client itself moves around the screen, instead of staying in place in the master.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong.  `client.swap.byidx` and `client.cycle` are subtly yet decidedly distinct.  Also what do you mean by "master"?